# 3D sparse datastructure or database in python for easy calling

Tags: python, database, optimization, data-structures

I'm coding up an optimisation problem in Python. The base object is a variable-object with 3 degrees of freedom.

W_(order, machine, time)

every order number between the first and the last will be populated (there will be no sparseness). However every order does not need every machine. For simplicity at this time every order-machine combo will have the entire  time-dimension populated but this could change.

I would like to easily call things like:

- All orders using machine 1 and 3
- All machines used by orders 1 and 5.
- All time variables of machines 2 and 3

and be returned nice iterable types (like a list) so that I can add the necessary constraints and whatnot.

```
        ----------------------- /|      
    M |  -   -    4    -    -  | |
    A |  3   -    -    -    -  | |
    C |  2   -    -    2    2  | |
    H |  -   1    -    -    1  | | 
      |  -   -    0    -    -  |/ Time
        -----------------------  
         0   1    2    3    4 
              ORDERS <-->
```

The simplest thing I can think of that will work is creating a 3D list in python and filling the blank spaces with Nulls? I'm not sure how well this will work with iterating. Or more complicated calls like:

time variables between 2..5 for orders 1 and 3 etc.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: So what's the reason for the desire of sparse data structures? Memory or performance? What are the dimensions we are talking about? If memory is not a problem, just use dense numpy-arrays (not lists!). This would allow some very powerful indexing like ```a[:, (1,3), :]```, ```a[(1,5), :, :]```, ```a[:, (2,3), :]```.

Comment: I need sparse data structures because I don't want to create unnecessary variables as it will slow down the optimisation procedure.

Comment: That's very imprecise. What is the origin of this slowdown? What kind of opt-procedure? (all my examples are linear-time in the number of results; of course this eval is dependent on the exact needs/usage; and there is also theory vs. practical performance)

Comment: It's a huge MILP problem where this is one part of it (it's a MIP). It'll be solved through a combination of the Simplex Algorithm and branch and bound procedures (but I'm not 100% on this - I'm using Gurobi solver). It most certainly is not linear wrt. time

Comment: Plus when I ask for the machines contained in an order I need only valid results, which I'm not sure how to do if it was dense since all the 'slots' would be filled

Comment: @sascha sorry I think I get why you were confused. These variables are not being fed directly into a solver. I am not creating any of my base matrices to then do math to. It's just a way to store a variable-object easily so I can call it within my program to add it to constraints essentially. Gurobi is creating the matrices behind the scenes.